# Pandas - Add columns based on grouping of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add three additional columns using pandas and python. I'm not sure how to add additional columns based on rows who have the same GroupID value.

- **min_avg**: Which is the lowest **avg** value for rows with the same GroupID
- **max_avg**: Which is the highest **avg** value for rows with the same GroupID
- **group_avg**: Which is the avg value for each rows '**min_avg**, **max_avg**' columns

I'm not entirely sure where to begin with this one.

I have this:

```
    avg     groupId
0   25.5    1016
1   26.7    1048
2   25.8    1016
3   53.5    1048
4   29.3    1064
5   27.7    1016
```

and my goal is this:

```
    avg         groupId     min_avg     max_avg     group_average
0   25.5        1016        25.5        27.7        26.6
1   26.7        1048        26.3        53.5        39.9
2   25.8        1016        25.5        27.7        26.6
3   53.5        1048        26.3        53.5        39.9
4   29.3        1064        29.3        29.3        29.3
5   27.7        1016        25.5        27.7        26.6
```

Comment: Look at `groupby(..).transform(..)`.  You want `min`, `max`, and then average those two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `describe` method, as given in YOBEN_S's solution, will compute more statistics than is required, including `count`, `std`, and `dtypes`. See [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html).

We can get around this by using the `agg` method.

```
df.merge(df.groupby('groupId')['avg'].agg([min, max, 'mean']), on='groupId')

# output
avg groupId min max mean
0   25.5    1016    25.5    27.7    26.333333
1   26.7    1048    26.7    53.5    40.100000
2   25.8    1016    25.5    27.7    26.333333
3   53.5    1048    26.7    53.5    40.100000
4   29.3    1064    29.3    29.3    29.300000
5   27.7    1016    25.5    27.7    26.333333
```

## Speed Comparison

**Approach 1**

```
%%timeit -n 1000

df.merge(df.groupby('groupId').avg.describe()[['mean','min','max']].reset_index(),how='left')
```

> 9.6 ms ± 123 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

**Approach 2**

```
%%timeit -n 1000

df.merge(df.groupby('groupId')['avg'].agg([min, max, 'mean']), on='groupId')
```

> 3.42 ms ± 74.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

**Approach 3**

Additionally, we can get a slight speedup by converting `df.merge` to `df.join`.

> 2.96 ms ± 29.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: is it possible for me to name the columns as i create them or do they have to be named mean, min and max?

Comment: You can use `rename` to change the column names, as so: `df.rename({"min":"min_avg", "max":"max_avg", "mean":"group_average"}, axis=1, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 4):

We can do `merge` with `groupby` `describe`

```
df=df.merge(df.groupby('groupId').avg.describe()[['mean','min','max']].reset_index(),how='left')
Out[25]: 
    avg  groupId       mean   min   max
0  25.5     1016  26.333333  25.5  27.7
1  26.7     1048  40.100000  26.7  53.5
2  25.8     1016  26.333333  25.5  27.7
3  53.5     1048  40.100000  26.7  53.5
4  29.3     1064  29.300000  29.3  29.3
5  27.7     1016  26.333333  25.5  27.7
```